# Jquery Datatables warning saying Unknown parameter

Tags: jquery, jsp, datatables, struts-1

jquery Datatables intialisation:

```
 var extensions = {
            "sFilter": "dataTables_filter manage_custom_filter_class",
            "sLength": "dataTables_length manage_custom_length_class",
            "sWrapper": "dataTables_wrapper",
            "sStripeOdd": "dataTables-odd-row",
            "sStripeEven ": "dataTables-even-row"
        }
  $.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oJUIClasses, extensions);
  $(".manage-sms-template-table").dataTable({
         "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
      "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
      "bJQueryUI": true,
      "bProcessing": true,
      "sAjaxDataProp":"",
      "sAjaxSource": "notification.do?method=getSmsData",
      "aoColumns": [
                  { "mDataProp": "smsCategory", "bSortable": true, "sClass": "manage-sms-row-category"},
                  { "mDataProp": "smsContent", "bSortable": true, "sClass": "manage-sms-row-content" },
                  {"mDataProp": null,
                      "sClass": "manage-sms-row-buttons" ,
                      "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                          return '<div class="manage-sms-row-buttons-edit"><a href="notification.do?method=showEditSmsTemplate&id='+oObj.aData["smsTemplateId"]+'"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a> </div>'+
                        '<div class="manage-sms-row-buttons-view"><a href="notification.do?method=showEditSmsTemplate&type=view&id='+oObj.aData["smsTemplateId"] +'"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i></a></div>'+
                        '<div class="manage-sms-row-buttons-delete"><a href="notification.do?method=deleteSMSTemplate&id='+oObj.aData["smsTemplateId"] +'"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></div>'
                    }}
              ],
     "oTableTools": {
         "sSwfPath": "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/dataTables/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
         "aButtons": [
                      {
                          "sExtends": "csv",
                          "mColumns": [ 0, 1]
                      },
                      {
                          "sExtends": "xls",
                          "mColumns": [ 0, 1]
                      },
                      {
                          "sExtends": "pdf",
                          "mColumns": [ 0, 1]
                      },
                  ]
      },
      "aaSorting": [[ 1, "desc" ]]
  });
```

Json: Data

```
[{"smsTemplateId":2,"smsContent":"Test Template","smsCategory":"category1:changes"},
{"smsTemplateId":3,"smsContent":"Test Template 3","smsCategory":"category2:Updates"},
{"smsTemplateId":4,"smsContent":"Test Template 4","smsCategory":"category3:Changes"}]
```

I want to display 3columns. SMScontent, smsCategory, 3rd column with buttons

when I am displaying the page getting Datatables warning, but when I click on "OK" button page is loading fine without any errror. Then why this warning is being displayed on refresh or pageload.

[image]

Datatables is initialises on body onload function.

How to resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you initializing the DataTable more than one time? `$(".manage-sms-template-table").dataTable(...` and then on the body? That might be the problem.

Comment: @azeós: No I am only initializing it once on body load.

Comment: when I remove fnRender() it works fine. What is the issue with that fnRender function

Answer (score 0):

You either have less/more columns or you misspelled any of the column's names. Check if you are passing the column that you've defined on `<th>` of `<table>`.